# generate and submit form - simple solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, submit, form-submit

I tried to use this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('<form method=POST action=/logout>').submit();return false;">
  Sign out
</a>
```

But `$('<form method=POST action=/logout>').submit();` doesn't work in Firefox ang IE.

Is there an equally simple solution for inline using?

**Current solution:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#logoutForm').submit();return false;">
Sign out
</a>
<form id="logoutForm" method="post" action="/logout"></form>
```

But I still want to understand why Firefox don't want to run jQuery `$('<form method=POST action=/logout>').submit();`. And what is the right way for FF?

Comment: Insert the dynamic form into the DOM first, the click/submit it. This should work on all browsers.

Comment: Of cource, if I add `<form id=myForm method=POST action=/logout></form>` then I can submit it `$('#myForm').submit();`. But I want one-line solution.

Comment: Why would you want a 1 line solution? If you really want that, make your logout method a GET request.

Comment: You mean `<a href='/logout'>Sign out</a>`? Then page will blink - and I want "ajax-way" behavior.

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(), $.post('login',function(req){console.log('success');});">` i hope you consider to chnage this behavior.

Comment: With this solution server can't make redirect. And you will have to do it instead of `console.log("success");` in every place.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me... I meant add the form to the DOM dynamically. I have added a working example below. Works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want it in a single line, try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('body').append('<form id=\'submitme\' method=\'POST\' action=\'/logout\'></form>');$('#submitme').submit();return false;">
  Sign out
</a>
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wWj2M/

I have tried this fiddle in these browsers successfully:

- IE
- Chrome
- Firefox

Note: your original did not generate "complete" HTML, so I added missing quotes and closing form element.

*Also tested now with a self-closing form tag, but that is not allowed so stick with the example above.*

Answer (score 0):

I can't write comments yet so I'll say this here. I'm not sure why would you want to do it like that and not use the normal way (since you don't seem to actually post any data)

```
<a href="#" href='/logout'>
  Sign out
</a>
```

or

```
<form method=POST action=/logout>
  <input type="submit" value='Sign out'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Firstly: page blinks with that, and I want "ajax-way". Second reason: server awaits POST, not GET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to do this INLINE... but:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(), $.post('login',function(req){console.log('success');});">
```

this function (is a callback of the async request - **ajax-way**):

```
function(req){console.log('success',req);}
```

allows you to manipulate the returned value `req`.

Comment: With this solution server can't make redirect. And you will have to do it instead of `console.log("success");` in every place.

Comment: sure. It's an **ajax** request. this not change the current position. To redirect after post (after creation a session or cookies, to mantain the login) you must do this in javascript: `location.href = 'http://otherplace.com'` instead `console.log();`